# Is this a correct implementation of a .indexOf? Javascript

Tags: javascript, indexof

I've tested my implementation of `.indexOf`, and it seems to work on my test cases, but I've seen other solutions where they add in the if condition `array[i] === elem && notFound === -1`. What is the purpose of the second condition? This is my version:

```
var indexOf = function (array, elem) { 
  var notFound = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === elem) {return i;}
  }
  return notFound;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a `array.contains(string)` like function?

Comment: Adding `&& notFound === -1` here isn't necessary, it will never be anything but -1.  You can delete that variable and just return -1 after the for loop if you want.

Comment: Input values are better to checked for wrong values.

Comment: What spec do you want to implement `indexOf` against? Your code does what it does, but we can't tell you whether that is wrong or not.

Comment: Can you show an example of the code where the extra condition is used? I could imagine a code which doesn't return early when the condition passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation seems fine to me.

I suspect the extra check is in a version of the function that doesn't break out of the loop when it finds a match. When it finds a match it sets `notFound = i;`, and keeps looping (unnecessarily); when the loop is done, it returns `notFound`. Testing whether `notFound === -1` prevents it from updating the variable if it finds a second match.

If that's not it, it would help if you actually posted an example of an implementation that uses the check you showed. It could just be a mistake -- just because you found code on the Internet, it doesn't mean it's correct.

Answer (score -1):

Take look at the following polyfill ([**from mdn**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill)) :

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.14
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.14
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

    var k;

    // 1. Let o be the result of calling ToObject passing
    //    the this value as the argument.
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
    }

    var o = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get
    //    internal method of o with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = o.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If len is 0, return -1.
    if (len === 0) {
      return -1;
    }

    // 5. If argument fromIndex was passed let n be
    //    ToInteger(fromIndex); else let n be 0.
    var n = +fromIndex || 0;

    if (Math.abs(n) === Infinity) {
      n = 0;
    }

    // 6. If n >= len, return -1.
    if (n >= len) {
      return -1;
    }

    // 7. If n >= 0, then Let k be n.
    // 8. Else, n<0, Let k be len - abs(n).
    //    If k is less than 0, then let k be 0.
    k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

    // 9. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {
      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the
      //    HasProperty internal method of o with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      //    i.  Let elementK be the result of calling the Get
      //        internal method of o with the argument ToString(k).
      //   ii.  Let same be the result of applying the
      //        Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm to
      //        searchElement and elementK.
      //  iii.  If same is true, return k.
      if (k in o && o[k] === searchElement) {
        return k;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Comment: Answers aren't really supposed to depend on external links if they can help it, and there's a consensus that "link-only answers" are almost always unsuitable. You may want to make this a comment instead.